# Nav bar stuck under slideshow html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with the navigation bar where it interferes with the slideshow, at the momment it underneth the slideshow. What is the best way to fix this? Here is the code below, any tips appreciated. Papa Bless. pretty newb to coding, any other points would be valued

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Home - A.Willi A.G</title>
</head>

<h1 align="center">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="A.Willi A.G" /></a>
</h1>

<body><link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" /></body>

<head>
<style>
.menu_div{background-color: #333; width:100%;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; 

}

li {
    float: left;

}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: black;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="menu_div">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Info</a>
        <a href="#">Jobs</a>

  <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="personalverleih.html">Personalverleih</a>
        <a href="toolrental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a>
        <a href="referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
        <a href="quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a>
        <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </body>




        <style>
        @keyframes fade {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        11.11%   { opacity: 1; }
        33.33%  { opacity: 1; }
        44.44%  { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
}

    .fadein { position:relative; height:332px; width:500px; outline: 1px solid blue; }
    .fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; opacity:0; animation-name: fade; animation-duration: 9s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    .fadein img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s;  }

       </style>
       <div class="fadein">
       <img src="welder1.png">
       <img src="welder2.png">
       <img src="welder3.png">
       </div>
       </body>       
       </html>
```

> Blockquote

```
body { font-family: verdana; background:white ; color: white; }


.nav{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;   
}

}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}

.fadein img {
    height:500px;
    width:381%;
}
```

> Blockquote

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Nothing should be located between head and body.

Comment: There should be only one head and one body.

Comment: [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) could help you with placing the nav bar on top of the slider, [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) could help you with how the elements are displayed on the page, [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) could help with the positioning of the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made some HTML and CSS formatting mistakes.
Fixed code look below. A problem that you described arised of style definition of `ul` element - to fix your problem you need to apply `z-ndex` over there.

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

```css
.menu_div{background-color: #333; width:100%;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: black;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   z-index: 100;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

        @keyframes fade {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        11.11%   { opacity: 1; }
        33.33%  { opacity: 1; }
        44.44%  { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
}

    .fadein { position:relative; height:332px; width:500px; outline: 1px solid blue; }
    .fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; opacity:0; animation-name: fade; animation-duration: 9s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    .fadein img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s;  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Home - A.Willi A.G</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
 <h1 align="center">
 <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="A.Willi A.G" /></a>
 </h1>
 <div class="menu_div">
        <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Info</a>
    <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="personalverleih.html">Personalverleih</a>
     <a href="toolrental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a>
     <a href="referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
     <a href="quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
       <div class="fadein">
     <img src="http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-blank-magazine-isolated-on-white-background-120442747.jpg">
     <img src="welder2.png">
     <img src="welder3.png">
       </div>

</body>       
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix it addinng z-index:1000; to css, cheers kevin

```
.menu_div { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  border: dashed;
  height: 2.9em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  z-index:1000
```